# Guzzle on_redirect not working

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) 
I'm having troubles with on_redirect.

I have basic sample here:

```
$client = new Client([ 
'handler' => $stack, 
'allow_redirects' => [ 
            'on_redirect' => function () {echo '123';},         
             'track_redirects' => true, ], 
]);
```

And it's not working.

Redirect middleware is included.

Can somebody please explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "its not working." - what happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: :) :)
for example, if i send get request to xyc.com which its redirecting to https://xyc.com i was expecting echo '123' (does not happen)

But i got response from https://xyc.com, which means redirection is working.

Comment: I am having the same problem.

Comment: Okay, so for me, the problem was that I was also passing `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` as a `curl` option to Guzzle.